# How to get A Path from a nested object tree

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am currently stuck with a problem that when I started out seemed not too hard to solve for me, but I am stuck for a couple of hours now, so here we go:

Given this nested objects/tree:

```
const tree = {
    value: 50, children: [
        {
            value: 17, children: [
                {
                    value: 12, children:
                        [
                            { value: 9, children: null },
                            { value: 14, children: null }
                        ]
                },
                { value: 23, children: null }
            ]
        }, {
            value: 72, children: [
                {
                    value: 54, children: [
                        {
                            value: 67, children: null
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    value: 76, children: null
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
}
```

I am trying to find a function that gives me the path to a value

```
function findPath(tree, target){
...
}
```

and the function will return something like

```
findPath(tree, 67);
<==============>
[50, 72, 54, 67]
```

I'm new to code. I hope I'll get you help to solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion to find the path (see comments in code):

```js
function findPath({ value, children }, target) {  
  if(value === target) return [value] // if the value is found return it wrap in an array
  
  for(const child of children ?? []) { // iterate the children or an empty array
    const leaf = findPath(child, target) // use findPath on all children
    
    if(leaf) return [value, ...leaf] // if a leaf is found (not null) spread it to the current array, and return it
  }
  
  return null
}

const tree = {"value":50,"children":[{"value":17,"children":[{"value":12,"children":[{"value":9,"children":null},{"value":14,"children":null}]},{"value":23,"children":null}]},{"value":72,"children":[{"value":54,"children":[{"value":67,"children":null}]},{"value":76,"children":null}]}]}

const result = findPath(tree, 67)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you! I really really appreciate your help. I've learned a lot about how to think differently from you all.

Answer (score 0):

One option with trees is recursion. Recursively search children until the value is found. On the way back up, build the array. Not sure this is the most efficient but it works.

```js
const tree = {
  value: 50,
  children: [{
    value: 17,
    children: [{
        value: 12,
        children: [{
            value: 9,
            children: null
          },
          {
            value: 14,
            children: null
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        value: 23,
        children: null
      }
    ]
  }, {
    value: 72,
    children: [{
        value: 54,
        children: [{
          value: 67,
          children: null
        }]
      },
      {
        value: 76,
        children: null
      }
    ]
  }],
};

function findPath(tree, target) {
  // The value of this node
  let currentValue = tree.value;
  if (currentValue == target) return [target];
  for (let t of Object.entries(tree)) {
    // Search children
    if (t[0] == "children" && t[1]) {
      for (let child of t[1]) {
        let found = findPath(child, target);
        if (found) {
          return [currentValue].concat(found);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // Not found in this branch
  return null;
}

console.log(findPath(tree, 67));
```

Comment: Thank you, man! I really really appreciate your help. I've learned a lot about how to think differently from you all. I never knew about all those things.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#:%7E:text=Depth%2Dfirst%20search%20(DFS),along%20each%20branch%20before%20backtracking.), a tree traversal algorithm.

```js
function findPath(tree, target) {    
    const path = [];
    const stack = [tree];

    while (stack.length) {
        let curr = stack.pop();
        path.push(curr.value);
        if (curr.value === target)  return path;
        if (curr.children !== null) {
            curr.children.forEach(child => stack.push(child));
        } else {
            path.pop();
        }
    }
    
    // target not found
    return [];
}

const tree = {"value":50,"children":[{"value":17,"children":[{"value":12,"children":[{"value":9,"children":null},{"value":14,"children":null}]},{"value":23,"children":null}]},{"value":72,"children":[{"value":54,"children":[{"value":67,"children":null}]},{"value":76,"children":null}]}]};

console.log(findPath(tree, 67));
```

Comment: Thank you. I really really appreciate your help. I've learned a lot about how to think differently.

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion to search for the tree, I have tried to write code in simplest way

```
const tree = {
        value: 50, children: [
            {
                value: 17, children: [
                    {
                        value: 12, children:
                            [
                                { value: 9, children: null },
                                { value: 14, children: null }
                            ]
                    },
                    { value: 23, children: null }
                ]
            }, {
                value: 72, children: [
                    {
                        value: 54, children: [
                            {
                                value: 67, children: null
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        value: 76, children: null
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
    }
    function find(tree,target,arr){
        if(tree.value === target)
        {
           arr.push(tree.value);   
           return true;
        }
        if(tree.children == null){
           return false;
        }
        let n = tree.children.length;
        for(let i = 0;i < n;i++){
            
            arr.push(tree.value);
            if(find(tree.children[i],target,arr))
                return true;
            arr.pop();
        }
        return false;
    }
    function findPath(tree,target){
        let arr=[];
        find(tree,target,arr);
        console.log(arr);
    }
    findPath(tree,67);
```

Comment: Thank you, man! I really really appreciate your help. I've learned a lot about how to think differently from you all. Its great to know there are all these ways to solve one problem.